# Alternative for mysql_insert_id in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading

I google the mysql_insert_id, about the thread safe concern... ...I am worrying about I only have a one MySQL user to connect DB, so, I think mysql_insert_id is not very safe for my application. Is there any "safer" method for returning last insert id from MySQL? thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with *[...]I only have a one MySQL user to connect DB, so, I think mysql_insert_id is not very safe for my application[...]*? Can you elaborate this?

Comment: @Stefan Gehrig - I think he (wrongly) believes that the last ID is not a session value but, instead, it's shared by all sessions depending on the user credentials.

Answer (score 5):

As long as no two threads share one database connection you should not get any wrong ids. `mysql_insert_id` is stored per connection, not per user.

Answer (score 1):

There is no safer method and you don't need any. `mysql_insert_id()` in PHP or `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the last `ID` per your current connection, **not per user account**, so you are perfectly safe here.

Comment: what is the connection means....if I submit a insert db request, than, I have the second one inserting using AJAX, is that mean it is two separate connection?

Comment: @Ted, the connection means the connection. When you call `mysql_connect`, it starts new connection. It ends with `mysql_close` or when the script ends.