# PHP Redirect to uploaded page after Form Submit?

Tags: php, mysql, header

In this program, a user is uploading a photo into MYSQL. Photoid is auto-incremented. Once the user submits the form, the code below takes action. I want the user to be redirected to the page the photo was just uploaded to. How can I redirect him to `photopage.php?photoid=???`.

```
 $addaphoto_query = "INSERT INTO `photosite`.`photos` (id, photoid, title, description) VALUES ('$id', '', '$title', '$description')";

    if ($run_addaphoto = mysqli_query($connect, $addaphoto_query){
         header('Location: photopage.php?photoid=???');
    }
```

Comment: SELECT id FROM `photosite` ORDER BY id DESC limit 1

Comment: and please do add `exit();` after the `header('');` function, no need to load the rest after that ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the PHP function [`mysqli_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php). This gets you the Photo ID.

```
if ($run_addaphoto = mysqli_query($connect, $addaphoto_query){
    header('Location: photopage.php?photoid=' . mysqli_insert_id());
}
```

In case you are wondering, `mysqli_insert_id()` is safe no matter how much traffic you get. [More reading on this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315200/is-it-possible-for-mysqli-insert-id-to-return-an-incorrect-id-in-high-traffic-ap)

**[From the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/getting-unique-id.html)**

> For LAST_INSERT_ID(), the most recently generated ID is maintained in
>   the server on a per-connection basis. It is not changed by another
>   client. It is not even changed if you update another AUTO_INCREMENT
>   column with a nonmagic value (that is, a value that is not NULL and
>   not 0). Using LAST_INSERT_ID() and AUTO_INCREMENT columns
>   simultaneously from multiple clients is perfectly valid. Each client
>   will receive the last inserted ID for the last statement that client
>   executed.

Comment: be careful with `mysql_insert_id()`. If there are multiple queries or users runing the code, it could return a wrong value.

Comment: @Ander2 "There is no safer method and you don't need any. mysql_insert_id() in PHP or SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the last ID per your current connection, not per user account." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855549/alternative-for-mysql-insert-id-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mysqli_insert_id()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) to get the id you have just inserted.

```
    $addaphoto_query = "INSERT INTO `photosite`.`photos` (id, photoid, title, description) VALUES      ('$id', '', '$title', '$description')";

    if ($run_addaphoto = mysqli_query($connect, $addaphoto_query){
         header('Location: photopage.php?photoid='.mysqli_insert_id().');
    }
```